# Don't understand source of this attribute not found error in this tkinter calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def Aman():
    class Calculator:
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            master.title("My Calculator")
            master.configure(bg='#cb464e')

            self.screen = Text(master, state='disabled', width=70, height=3, background='#fcfcec', foreground='#cb464e', font=("times", 12, "bold"))

            self.screen.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=6, pady=6)
            self.screen.configure(state="normal")

            self.equation = " "

            b1 = self.createButton(7)
            b2 = self.createButton(8)
            b3 = self.createButton(9)
            b4 = self.createButton(u"\u232B")
            b5 = self.createButton(4)

            b6 = self.createButton(5)
            b7 = self.createButton(6)
            b8 = self.createButton(u"\u00F7")
            b9 = self.createButton(1)
            b10 = self.createButton(2)
            b11 = self.createButton(3)
            b12 = self.createButton("*")
            b13 = self.createButton(".") #point
            b14 = self.createButton(0)
            b15 = self.createButton("+") #add
            b16 = self.createButton("-") #minus
            b17 = self.createButton("=", None, 34)

            buttons = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, 17]
            count = 0

            for row in range(1,5):
                for column in range (4):
                    buttons[count].grid(row=row, column=column)
                    count += 1
            buttons[16].grid(row=5, column=0,columnspan=4)
            def createButton(self, val, write=True, width=7):

                return Button(self.master, text=val, command=lambda:
                    self.click(val, write), width=width, background= "#345872", foreground="#fcfcec", font=("times", 20))

            def click(self, text, write):
                if write == None:
                    if text  == "=" and self.equation:
                        self.equation = re.sub(u"\u00F7", "/", self.equation)
                        print(self.equation)
                        answer = str(eval(self.equation))
                        self.clear_screen()
                        self.insert_screen(answer, newline=True)
                    elif text == u"\u2322B":
                        self.clear_screen()
                else:
                    self.insert_screen(text)

            def clear_screen(self):
                self.equation = " "
                self.screen.configure(state= "normal")
                self.screen.delete("1.0", END)

            def insert_screen(self, value, newline=False):
                self.screen.configure(state="normal")
                self.screen.insert(END, value)

                #rec values
                self.equation += str(value)
                self.screen.configure(state = "disabled")

    root = Tk()
    my_gui = Calculator(root)
    root.mainloop()

Aman()
```

Problem:

The terminal returns the following errors:
im not sure what the problem is. It says that `Calculator` has no attribute. It is connected to the top so it should not be giving that error.
As for `my_gui = Calculator(root)`, I'm not sure if that is a problem as a result of the calculator not having an atribute.

```
PS C:\Users\Amanh> & C:/Users/Amanh/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Users/Amanh/Desktop/Python/CalculatorTkinter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Amanh/Desktop/Python/CalculatorTkinter.py", line 78, in <module>
    Aman()
  File "c:/Users/Amanh/Desktop/Python/CalculatorTkinter.py", line 76, in Aman
    my_gui = Calculator(root)
  File "c:/Users/Amanh/Desktop/Python/CalculatorTkinter.py", line 17, in __init__
    b1 = self.createButton(7)
AttributeError: 'Calculator' object has no attribute 'createButton'
PS C:\Users\Amanh>
```

Comment: Your functions are indented too far. They all need to be at the save level as `__init__`.

Comment: Your function in Calculator class (except __init__) seems wrongly indented. You have to de l'été one i dent...

Comment: Agree it's a code indention problem. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The are two problems mainly indent of `__init__` and typo where `17` shoud be `b17` at the end of this line:

```
buttons = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, 17]
```

After correction:

```py
#/usr/local/python
from tkinter import *


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("My Calculator")
        master.configure(bg='#cb464e')
        
        self.screen = Text(master, state='disabled', width=70, height=3, background='#fcfcec', foreground='#cb464e', font=("times", 12, "bold"))
        
        self.screen.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=6, pady=6)
        self.screen.configure(state="normal")
        
        self.equation = " "
        
        b1 = self.createButton(7)
        b2 = self.createButton(8)
        b3 = self.createButton(9)
        b4 = self.createButton(u"\u232B")
        b5 = self.createButton(4)

        b6 = self.createButton(5) 
        b7 = self.createButton(6)
        b8 = self.createButton(u"\u00F7")
        b9 = self.createButton(1)
        b10 = self.createButton(2)
        b11 = self.createButton(3)
        b12 = self.createButton("*")
        b13 = self.createButton(".") #point
        b14 = self.createButton(0)
        b15 = self.createButton("+") #add
        b16 = self.createButton("-") #minus
        b17 = self.createButton("=", None, 34)
        
        buttons = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12, b13, b14, b15, b16, b17]
        count = 0
                
        for row in range(1,5):
            for column in range (4):
                buttons[count].grid(row=row, column=column)
                count += 1 
        buttons[16].grid(row=5, column=0,columnspan=4)

    def createButton(self, val, write=True, width=7): 
        return Button(self.master, text=val, command=lambda:
            self.click(val, write), width=width, background= "#345872", foreground="#fcfcec", font=("times", 20))
            
    def click(self, text, write):
        if write == None:
            if text  == "=" and self.equation:
                self.equation = re.sub(u"\u00F7", "/", self.equation)
                print(self.equation)
                answer = str(eval(self.equation))
                self.clear_screen()
                self.insert_screen(answer, newline=True)
            elif text == u"\u2322B": 
                self.clear_screen()
        else:
            self.insert_screen(text)
            
    def clear_screen(self):
        self.equation = " "
        self.screen.configure(state= "normal")
        self.screen.delete("1.0", END)
        
    def insert_screen(self, value, newline=False):
        self.screen.configure(state="normal")
        self.screen.insert(END, value)
        
        #rec values 
        self.equation += str(value)
        self.screen.configure(state = "disabled")


def Aman():     
    root = Tk()
    my_gui = Calculator(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Aman()
```